# Proving a multi-variable function is injective given this function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm not really sure how to tackle this question.
$f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $f(n,k)=2^{n+1}(4k+3)$ is injective. I don't really even know how to start..

Could someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: What is the definition of being injective? Start there.

Comment: $x_1 = x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) = f(x_2)$

Comment: Is it possible to prove this without prime factorization?

Comment: Hello @MihaiBarbaneagra! Pay attection: injectivity is: $f(x)=f(y) \Longrightarrow x=y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(n_1,k_1) = f(n_2,k_2)$; we have to prove $n_1=n_2$ and $k_1 = k_2$.

We have $2^{n_1+1}(4k_1+3) = 2^{n_2+1}(4k_2+3)$. The idea is to compare separately the odd and even part of this numbers.

For the equality, we have $2^{n_2+1}$ divides $2^{n_1+1}(4k_1+3)$ because all are integers. Since $(4k_1+3)$ is odd, then the $\gcd(2^{n_2+1},(4k_1+3))=1$, so we must have $2^{n_2+1}$ divides $2^{n_1+1}$. Thanks to this fact we obtain $n_2+1 \leq n_1 +1\Longrightarrow n_2\leq n_1$. Switching the indices and repeating the argument you also obtain $n_1\leq n_2$ and then $n_1=n_2$

Now (thanks to $n_1=n_2$) your first equality become $(4k_1+3) = (4k_2+3)$ that easily implies $k_1=k_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how you did it.. Could you please explain how you could just treat every  piece individually? is that because we're working with natural numbers which are always positive?

Comment: Could you just elaborate a little?

Comment: @MihaiBarbaneagra Hello! I edited my answer in order to include more details

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** Use factorization. Notice that $4k+3$ is never even (why? show this!) and that $2^{n+1}$ is only ever divisible by $2$. Then whatever number $f(n,k)$ is, all its factors of $2$ come from $2^{n+1}$ and all the rest of its prime factors come from $4k+3$. Suppose then that $f(n,k)= f(n',k')$ for some $n,n',k,k'$, i.e. $2^{n+1} (4k+3)= 2^{n'+1}(4k'+3)$. Given what you know about the factorizations, can you relate certain parts of this equality? What lets you do this? Then what must this imply about $n,n'$ and $k,k'$?